# Why should I use IWindowsFormsEditorService.ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, winforms

I've found some legacy code, which was used to display a dialog whenever the user clicks on a button in a custom property of a property page. It overrides the `EditValue` method of a custom `UITypeEditor`:

```
IWindowsFormsEditorService windowsFormsEditorService = serviceProvider.GetService( typeof( IWindowsFormsEditorService ) ) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
windowsFormsEditorService.ShowDialog( frmDialog );
```

As I want to replace the WinForms form by a WPF dialog I could create a form with an ElementHost, but simply calling `Window.ShowDialog` also seems to work like a charm. Is there any advantage of using the `IWindowsFormsEditorService` to show a modal dialog instead of just showing it directly? If there is none, why is the framework providing this method?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.iwindowsformseditorservice(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It ensures the dialog has the proper owner, an important detail for dialogs.  How you gave the WPF window the proper owner is not exactly obvious.

Comment: which should be quite useful in most of the cases though it's not required in my specific case...perfect answer...thank you, @HansPassant!